# Pass variables from Flow to LC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, variable

Hello everybody I am working on a flow that contains a screen Aura component. From the flow I want to pass two variables one from a recordId and other that has a text field value from a record.

In my LWC -meta.xml I have the configured the input properties:

```
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
           <property name="recordId" type="String" label="recordId" description="recorId" role="inputOnly"/>
           <property name="codigoSolicitud" type="String" label="codigoSolicitud" description="codigoSolicitud" role="inputOnly"/>
        </targetConfig>
      </targetConfigs>
```

And in my .cmp I have this:

```
       <c:qX_LWC_Formu recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
       <c:qX_LWC_Formu codigoSolicitud="{!v.codigoSolicitud}"/>
```

But the problem comes in the flow. The codigoSolicitud input ain´t appear:
[image]

Could anybody help me?

Comment: you need to add your `aura:attribute` to the aura's design file, as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens.htm)

Comment: You have a lwc that is set to be exposed as a lightning__FlowScreen but you also have an Aura component.  Please can you explain the relationship between the two and why you are not putting the lwc directly into the flow.